# How to split a string at a certain index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to split a string every 4 characters and push them into an array. I have been trying to loop through using .substring but my loop stops at the first 4 characters.

So  want to turn this string...

let list = "abcdefghijklmnop"

into this array...

[ "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"]

Comment: What about any odd spares?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a regular expression which searches for four characters.

```js
const
    list = "abcdefghijklmnop",
    parts = list.match(/.{1,4}/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a loop to iterate over the string and extracting substrings of 4 characters at a time.

Here's code to  achieve your result:

```
let list = "abcdefghijklmnop";
let resultArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 4) {
  let chunk = list.substring(i, i + 4);
  resultArray.push(chunk);
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

**Output:**

```
[ 'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop' ]
```